# AngularJs implementing a search feature

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean

I am making a simple online car shop with the MEAN stack.
I have some entities in the database and now I am trying to implement the search-feature. I have a page with search fields. On clicking the search button, a function is called in the controller making a post request to the server sending the options object. The server responds with correct data. And here is the problem: the Search button calls search function.

```
$scope.search = function(options) {
console.dir(options);
CarAdsService.searchByOptions(options)
  .then(function(cars) {
    $scope.cars = cars;
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

and the service function that is called:

```
searchByOptions: function(options) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http.post('/api/searchCars', {options: options})
    .success(function(cars){
    // when I log cars, the data is correct
      deferred.resolve(cars);
    })
    .error(function(err){
      deferred.reject(err);
    });


  return deferred.promise;
```

then in the view i got this:

```
 tr(ng-repeat="car in cars")
     td {{ car.brand.name }}
     td {{ car.model.name }}
     td {{ car.fuelType }}
     td {{ car.gearBox }}
     td {{ car.price | currency}}
     td {{ car.year }}
```

which is in a section right from the search menu, but it does not get updated. Tested many times, the $scope.cars object is correctly setted, but the view is not updated. I tried calling $scope.$apply() but it throws exception that $digest is already running. 
Could you give any idea how to work-around this?

Comment: Have you tried creating a `div` bound to just `cars` to see if the property is being updated correctly?

Comment: Are you sure that the view is in the correct scope?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turned out I am idiot (5 hours banging my head against the wall)

```
CarAdsService.searchByOptions(options)
  .then(function(cars) {
    $scope.cars = cars.cars;
```

the respond is an objects that has a cars proeprty, relating to the array.

Comment: You should probably delete the question since it wouldn't help anyone on stack! Very specific